# How to create a flickering light source using cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, animation-nodes

I tried doing this using the 'Noise' option in the F-Curve Modifier, but i did not see and significant flickering. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any other way this output can be achieved. 
Also, is there any way to rapidly and randomly change the shape of a object --like a sphere or icosphere -- to further assist the flickering effect?

Comment: Did you try turning up the strength of the noise modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing the strength value.

[image: Strength: noise]

Answer (score 1):

I used fcurve modifier to control the strength when practicing on a jackolantern.  It took me a decent about of tweaking to get it the way I wanted it.  Here are the results.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6bJn86UsSg

With a candle, what really helped was thinking that the "flicker" is actually when the flame or light is losing strength.  I picked what value was going to be the strongest (450 in my case)...and then only used the fcurve to decrease strength and then bring it back up to my "strongest" value.  But the difference in strength had to be pretty dramatic...as in..450 was my top, but I had to make the drops in strength be pretty close to 0...like I think around 20.

[image]